# Optimizer prevents system where variable is saved and changed, then interrupt is called and then variable is reset

Tags: c, compiler-optimization

I have a setup where I need to pass data to an interrupt. This is done through a global variable. But the issue I am facing is that this setup might be called from an interrupt and interrupts might nest. So I need the following setup:

1. Saved current value of global variable to variable on stack.
2. Call interrupt.
3. Restore value from variable on stack to global variable

I implemented this as follows:

```
extern volatile void* intrBlockObject;
...
volatile void* storeAddr = intrBlockObject;
intrBlockObject = object;
if (increase){
    CALLSUPERVISOR(SVC_multiObjectIncrease);
} else {
    CALLSUPERVISOR(SVC_multiObjectDecrease);
}
intrBlockObject = storeAddr;
```

This CALLSUPERVISOR part is an macro which translates to an interrupt.

This works, until an optimizer gets into play. Is there a setup possible for this problem where I can explain to the optimizer what I want? I would like to do this without compiler specific instructions, just in plain C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The declaration ...

```
volatile void* intrBlockObject;
```

(with or without `extern`) describes a pointer to a location whose *contents* are `volatile`.  The program must always read that object from main memory when it needs [part of] its value, and must always write changes to main memory.

That's not the same thing, however, as the *address* being `volatile`, and it's the address (the pointer value itself) that you are saving and restoring.  If other code (e.g. an interrupt handler) may modify that pointer unbeknownst to the C program, then you must make the *pointer* `volatile`:

```
void * volatile intrBlockObject;
```

If appropriate, pointer and pointed-to thing can both be `volatile`:

```
volatile void * volatile intrBlockObject;
```

This is completely analogous to usage of the `const` qualifier, in which context this sort of confusion is distressingly common.

Comment: Thank you! That fixed it. One more question: what is the difference between void volatile* name and void* volatile name?

Comment: `void volatile *` is the same as `volatile void *`.  If you want the pointer itself to be volatile then the `volatile` keyword must go *after* the `*`.